# How to create Text document in Python through two lists by making pairs in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, quotes

I am trying to create this specific text document:

a=1

b=2

c=3

d=4!

through these two lists:

```
keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
values = ["1", "2", "3", 4]
```

This is my code:

```
import json

keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
values = ["1", "2", "3", 4]

data = {key: val for key, val in zip(keys, values)}

with open('file.txt','w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f,separators=('\n','='))
```

My code is as follows, yet I cant figure out how to remove the quotation marks or the brackets. Finally I should be able to create a exclamation mark after the 4.
Any help is gladly appreciated, I am quite new to coding.
I want to save the list into a dictionary and then create a text file with a for loop.

Comment: you don't need `json` module. you can write the data directly to file

Comment: Why are you using `json` library for plain text?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to print the exclamation mark because the data type of the last element in the Tuple (List with more than one datatype) is different.

Also, it is unclear to me why you use a json.dump(...)

Using:

```
if type(values[i]) is int:
```

you can check if the value of element i is of type int

Using:

```
if type(values[i]) is not str:
```

you can check if the value of element i is not of type string

Then iterating over your lists by their length, You would get something like:

```
keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
values = ["1", "2", "3", 4]


F = open("file.txt", "w")
for i in range(len(keys)):
    line =f"{keys[i]}={values[i]}"
    if type(values[i]) is int:
        line+="!"
    F.write(line+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

File you want to create is not legal JSON. Your task might be easily tackled using so-called f-string (requires python 3.6 or newer) or other formatting mechanism. For example:

```
keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
values = ["1", "2", "3", 4]

lines = [f'{key}={val}' for key, val in zip(keys, values)]
lines[-1] = lines[-1] + "!"
text = "\n".join(lines)

with open('file.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

If you want know more about f-string I suggest reading [realpython's tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Comment: you can directly use `writelines()` without using `join()`